# Connecting two threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have two classes that extends Thread. Class One, and class Two.

In my driver class, I create three threads of class One, and one hundred threads of class Two.

Each class One thread needs to notify every class Two thread that it's available to interact. After the two threads interact,  the thread One moves on to another class Two thread that hasn't had an interaction with a class One thread.

How do I connect the two types of threads? How do I connect class 1 and class 2 threads. How does a thread using class 1 let every thread using class 2 know that it is available for interaction?

ex code:

```
public class Driver {
public static Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Teller tellerOne = new Teller(1);

    Teller tellerTwo = new Teller(2);

    Teller tellerThree = new Teller(3);

    tellerOne.start();
    tellerTwo.start();
    tellerThree.start();

    Client[] clients = new Client[10];

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        clients[i] = new Client(i);
        clients[i].start();
        }



    System.out.println("Bank closes");
    //end main method. do not write past this line
}




public class Teller extends Thread {

public int id;
public boolean bankOpen;
public Semaphore tsem;


Teller(int id){
    this.id = id;
}

public void run(){
    System.out.println("Teller " + id + " is available");



//end of run
}

//method to notify availability to client
public void notifyAvailabilityToClient(){

}


//end teller class, do not write past this line


public class Client extends Thread {

public int id;
public String status;
public Semaphore csem;


Client(int id){
    this.id = id;
}

public void run(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int withdrawOrDeposit = rand.nextInt(100);
    withdrawOrDeposit = withdrawOrDeposit%2;
    //if wORd%2 = 0, withdraw, else deposit

    if(withdrawOrDeposit==0){
        status="Withdraw";
    }
    else{
        status="Deposit";
    }

    System.out.println("Client " + id + " waits in line to make a " + status);


//end of run method, do not write past this 
}

//method to select an open Teller
public void selectAvailableTeller(){


}

//end of client class, do not write past this line
```

Btw I can use classes: Semaphore and Threads

Comment: You could share the `Semaphore` between them.

Comment: What does "*interact*" entail? Can you use `queue` classes?

Comment: @PM77-1 thread Two has data that it was initialized with, that it needs to transfer over to thread One. I'm not sure if I can use queue classes, but I believe I can.

Comment: So it's one-way communication? Then it sounds like a Producer-Consumer problem that is normally solved with queues of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not normally write code in which different threads meet up with each other, but since this appears to be a homework assignment...

In my solution there would be a single, blocking queue. When a "teller" thread starts up, and each time it finishes "interacting" with a customer, it would put its *self* into the queue, and then wait for a new customer to start an interaction. The customers all would wait to `take()` a teller from the queue, and when they get one,... "interact" with it.

---

If it was not homework I would do something entirely different. I don't know why "customer" threads are a thing, but I don't see any use for "teller" threads at all. There might be some kind of limited-availability `Teller` *objects*, but they would not be threads. The customer threads could "interact" by simply calling `Teller` methods or, if necessary, by submitting *tasks* that call `Teller` methods to a generic *thread pool*.

Comment: good response, I hope to impliment this in the next ~10 hours